# How can I dynamically create a report which returns records for a certain manager?

Tags: reporting

I understand how show filter works in report builder.

> My Opportunities: Searches ONLY the opportunities you OWN.
>
> My Team-selling opportunities: Searches ONLY the opportunities where
>   you are on the SALES TEAM.
>
> My Team-selling and my own Opportunities: Searches BOTH the
>   opportunities you OWN and the opportunities where you are on the SALES
>   TEAM.
>
> My Team's Opportunities: Searches ONLY the opportunities OWNED by you
>   and the users who report to you in the role hierarchy.
>
> My Team's Team-selling and their Opportunities: Searches the
>   opportunities OWNED by you and the users that report to you in the
>   role hierarchy, as well as opportunities where you or the users who
>   report to you in the role hierarchy are on the SALES TEAM.

How to create a dynamic report where I can filter by user's manager so that all the records owned by users for this specific manager could be returned?

Comment: You want a user to run a report and see all records owned by users who have the same manager as the user running the report?  That seems possible if you add a formula field to opps, pseudocode: $user.manager.id = opp.owner.manager.Id  then filter your report for that field = true.

Comment: create formula field on opportunity.  Add filter criteria to report that formulafield = true.

Comment: @gorav Yeah, it worked like charm. Please feel free to post your comments as an answer which I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: glad it worked - answer added.  cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a formula field to opportunities, that compares the running user's manager to the opp owner manager

Pseudocode: `manager_compare__c` >

```
$user.manager.id = opp.owner.manager.Id`
```

Then, add a filter to your report such that `manager_compare__c = true`.

All credit for this answer goes to SteveMo who talked about the idea of using $User in formula fields for reports and list views circa df 2010 :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a report filter. Adding these to a report reduces the data down to just records which fit inside the criteria you specify. You can use these filters to only pull records which have a specific user set in a given field.

I would read through the docs on this, which you can find [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_builder_filtering.htm&language=en_US).